# How do I do vector embedding of words using Ruby, without making calls to a third party API?

Tags: ruby, language-model

How do I make vector embeddings of words using Ruby, without making calls to a third party API? Just want to do it locally for speed and cost.

I can't find any good examples in Ruby.

Comment: Presumably, you'd have to reimplement the word2vec algorithm and run it on a large corpus of text.